# Two laptops authorized to play my iTunes library; what can each laptop see?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, sharing, data

There are two computers authorized to play my iTunes library; one is my main laptop and I sync my iPhone and iPad to this. The second laptop is an old one which I gave to a friend when I upgraded. I have no objections to her playing from my library. However, I am concerned now that she has bought her first iPhone.

When she syncs her device, what data (contacts, mail, texts etc.) will she be able to see of mine and vice versa?

Also if I download Apps will she automatically see them and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

You've actually posed two questions.

For the iTunes library, I'm assuming you've gone to the menu and Authorized This Machine to access your content. This authorizes the computer to access your paid content, meaning movies, tv shows, and songs downloaded through iTuens or via iTunes Match (if you enabled that on this machine too).

For contacts from your phone, did you enable iCloud on your old computer? If so you could have possibly enabled cloud syncing of contacts, mail, and calendar events. If you did this, then your friend will be getting whatever information you enabled. Thus to answer your other question, in this case she will automatically get your information.

Keep in mind that the Home Sharing feature, iTunes Match, and iTunes authorization End User Agreement License covers your household; thus, by allowing your friend to access your content you're technically violating the terms of service agreement.

If you want to to maintain your privacy, on your old machine go to System Preferences > iCloud and sign out. This will take care of your privacy concerns of contacts. In iTunes, go to Store > De Authorize This Computer, then Store > Sign Out

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to share your library: local network iTunes sharing and Home Sharing (capital H, capital S).

In the first case, the other person can see your content if both laptops are turned on and iTunes is open, but can't download it. This is best for casual music sharing, etc.

In the second case, either person can import items from iTunes libraries on the other computer, including apps. This is the same as sharing the same Apple ID, which would also mean that the other person can download content and leave you with the charges on your credit card. It's possible, since you're the former owner of the laptop, that you set this up by simply leaving the iTunes settings as they were and authorizing your new laptop to the same iTunes account. In this case probably the easiest thing to do is to change your password and tell your friend that she needs to set up her own Apple ID to use with iTunes.